# WPF Data Grid given date but rows are empty

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, xml-serialization

I am having trouble filling a `DataGrid` with data. Here is my code to deserialize an `XML file` and place the info into an array, and then put the `Array` into the `DataGrid` using the `ItemsSource` method.

```
public partial class Teacher_Page : Window
{
    List<User> pupils;

    public Teacher_Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<User>));
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader("../../../Pupils.xml");
        pupils = (List<User>)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
        textReader.Close();

        lbtest.Content = pupils[2].Name;
        dataResults.ItemsSource = pupils;

    }
}
```

However when I run the program my `DataGrid` is filled with the correct amount of rows for the `arraylist` however the rows are empty and there are no columns. `lbltest` outputs an string from the `arraylist` to prove that the `arraylist` is not empty, which is correct.
`AutoGenerateColumns` is set to true as well.

`XAML`

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataResults" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="248" Width="610" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

`Code behind`

```
public class User
{
    public String Name;
    public int Score;

    public User()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show declaration of `DataGrid` in XAML and structure of `User` class?

Comment: I have edited the original post with the added code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies within your `User` class.

To auto generate columns in dataGrid you should have `properties` in the underlying ItemsSource class and `not fields`. `Binding` from XAML works only with properties and not fields.

Make `Name` and `Score` as properties and then it should work -

```
public class User
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```